# detecting empty xml elements

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing

I've got the following code to read through an XML file the has the following elements within

```
<byline>name</byline>
<display_title>title</display_title>
<mpaa_rating>PG</mppa_rating>
```

i've got the following perl code to go through the xml document and print out the values of the above elements

```
use XML::DOM;
my $doc;
my $parser = new XML::DOM::Parser; 
    die "Unable to parse XML document\n" 
        unless $doc = $parser->parsefile ("../reviews.xml");

foreach $elem ($doc->getElementsByTagName ("review")) { 
    foreach $review($elem->getChildNodes){
        foreach $child ($review->getChildNodes) {       
            if($review->getTagName eq 'byline'){#name of tag
                print $child->getNodeValue."->";

            }
            if($review->getTagName eq 'display_title'){#name of tag
                 print $child->getNodeValue."->";

            }
            if($review->getTagName eq 'mpaa_rating'){#name of tag
                print $child->getNodeValue.";\n";
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The problem that occurs is that if an empty element is found, the program will coninue to print on the same line. e.g  when the program reaches `<mpaa_rating/>` the output will be
`name->title->name`. I would like the program to print `name->title->no Rating` if the rating is found.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`XML::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aDOM) hasn't been updated or maintained since 2005.  It has [`issues`](https://rt.cpan.org/Dist/Display.html?Name=XML-DOM) in the bug tracker marked as important that are 10 years old.  It would be advisable to not use this module.

Two superior alternatives are [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aTwig) and [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aLibXML).  `mirod` has already provided an implementation of the former.  Here is one for the latter:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(IO => \*DATA);

for my $review ($dom->findnodes('//review')) {
    my @values = map {$review->findvalue($_) || 'no'} qw(byline display_title mpaa_rating);
    print join("->", @values), "\n";
}

__DATA__
<root>
  <review>
    <byline>name</byline>
    <display_title>title</display_title>
    <mpaa_rating>PG</mpaa_rating>
  </review>
  <review>
    <byline>name 1</byline>
    <display_title>title 1</display_title>
    <mpaa_rating/>
  </review>
</root>
```

Outputs:

```
name->title->PG
name 1->title 1->no
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use XML::DOM, it's old, slow and poorly maintained. Use instead [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod), or [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aTwig).

The code will be very similar with XML::LibXML. You just need to add an else to your last test:

```
        if($review->getTagName eq 'mpaa_rating'){#name of tag
            print $child->getNodeValue.";\n";
        }
        else {
            print "no;\n";
        }
```

Using XML::Twig, here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.10.0;

use XML::Twig;

XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { review => \&review, })
         ->parse( \*DATA); # replace with ->parsefile( 'file.xml') to parse a file

sub review
  { my( $t, $review)= @_;
    my @values;
    foreach my $field ( qw( byline display_title mpaa_rating))
      { push @values, $review->field( $field) || 'no'; }
    say join( "->", @values), ";";
  }

__DATA__
<doc>
  <review>
    <byline>name</byline>
    <display_title>title</display_title>
    <mpaa_rating>PG</mpaa_rating>
  </review>
  <review>
    <byline>name 1</byline>
    <display_title>title 1</display_title>
    <mpaa_rating/>
  </review>
</doc>
```